# Performance do INNER JOIN em SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Olá, alguém saberia me dizer se há alguma diferença significativa de performance nas duas maneiras de fazer INNER JOIN abaixo?

Maneira 1:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Maneira 2:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Eu creio que a resposta deve depender do SGBD, estou mais interessado em bancos Oracle que são os que eu uso com mais frequência, mas se alguém souber a resposta para outros também seria legal saber!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em performance, não, mas em expressão de linguagem, sim. A Oracle recomenda sair das operações não-ANSI porque [elas são mais limitadas que as operações ANSI](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3175).

Além disso, como a sintaxe ANSI é um padrão aplicável a todos os bancos de dados, escrever tudo em ANSI facilita a portabilidade para outros bancos de dados, se isto for desejável no futuro.